# Find ids of checked checkboxes with jQuery in MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller

I have a Field model, which represents a certain field (Name, Description, ...)

```
class FieldModel : EntityModel
{    
    ...
    public bool ToCopy { get; private set; }
    public string Id {get; private set; }
    ...
}
```

An Index model, which has a collection of Fields:

```
class EntityModel
{
    ...
}

class IndexModel
{
    public IEnumerable<EntityModel> Fields { get; private set; }
}
```

Controller for copy, that should accept ids of fields to copy:

```
public void CopyFields(string[] fieldsIds)
{
    ...
}
```

And I need to select certain fields to copy by checkboxes. So in the vew for Field I added

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.IsSelectedForCopy)
```

In the view for Index

```
<button onclick="onCopyClick('@Model');" type="button" class="btn showButton">Copy Fields</button>
```

And now I need to write a script to select all checked fields and send their Ids to the controller. I have zero experience with Javascript/jQuery, so could someone help me with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should get you started at least ;)

You give jQuery some css selectors and it gives you the objects that match...

```
$("input :checked").each(function() {
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

Depending on how you want to send them, you could then append each id to a hidden field on a form like so:

```
$("input :checked").each(function() {
    var tmp = $("#myHiddenField").val();
    tmp += " " + $(this).attr("id"));
    $("#myHiddenField").val(tmp);
});
$.ajax("TheURLToPostTheDataTo", 
    {data: [
        {idsToSend:$("#myHiddenField").val()}
    ], 
    success:  function() { 
         alert("Done"); 
    }
});
```

Then submit, and on the serverside trim and split by space?

Comment: Thanks! How can I send this with ajax? Smth like this, as far as I understand?
onCopy: function(model) {
    var items = [your upper script]
    this.ajax {
        action:"CopyFields",
        data: items,
        context: model,
        success: function(vew) {
        }
    });
}