# get IEnumerable<T> in mvc post method argument

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have one model called ProductSupplier

I am passing @model IEnumerable to my View

and showing it from view
Now when i submit the form i m not getting list of IEnumerable in my http post method. I want to know the selected supplier from user.

Below is my model

```
public sealed class ProductSupplier
{
  public int CountryId { get; set; }
  public int UserId { get; set; }
  public bool IsProductSupplier { get; set; }
  public string CountryName { get; set; }
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  public string LastName { get; set; }
  public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

This is my HttpGet method

```
public ActionResult ManageSupplier(int id)
    {            
        var supplier = App.UsersRepo.GetSupplierForProduct(id);
        return View(supplier);
    }
```

And I am binding it via following way (U can suggest me best way I am new bee to MVC)

```
@model IEnumerable<ProductSupplier>
@using (Html.BeginForm("ManageSupplier", "Products", FormMethod.Post, new { role = "form") })
{   @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    foreach (var item in Model)
    {      
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => item.IsProductSupplier, new { id = item.Email }) @item.FirstName @item.LastName (@item.Email)
            </label>
        </div>       
    }
}
```

And finally my HttpPost method

```
[HttpPost]        
    public ActionResult ManageSupplier(IEnumerable<ProductSupplier> obj)
    {   // I m getting obj null in my argument
       //I want to Get selected id from obj and want to pass in  selectedSupplier
        var returnVal = App.ProductRepo.AssigneSupplierForProduct(productId, selectedSupplier);
        return Json(new { success = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
    }
```

can anyone suggest me where i m making mistake.
I am new to MVC any kind of suggestion highly appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: be sure App.UsersRepo.GetSupplierForProduct(id); return IEnumerable

Comment: Yes i am able to list them on view , only thing i need now when i select some checkbox on view i can get their detail on post method so i can apply appropriate db operation

Comment: The problem is ActionResult ManageSupplier(IEnumerable<ProductSupplier> obj) u only need ManageSupplier(ProductSupplier obj)

Comment: but i m passing list of ProductSupplier to view and i want selected supplier in my post method.

Comment: U list all ProductSupplier  on view and wanna crud operation only one ProductSupplier  ,rifgt?

Comment: Yes what i m doing is , I m showing list of available supplier in view. The selected supplier will be seen as checked in view and user can check/uncheck and i want that checked supplier (UserId of model ProductSupplier) in post

Comment: Only one ProductSupplier  wanna send to method right?

Comment: no we want all selected supplier..

Comment: You need to use a `for` loop or an `EditorTemplate` (not a `foreach` loop) if you want to bind to a collection. Its not clear why you are taking this approach. If you only want to select one supplier from a list, use a dropdown or a group of radio buttons. If you want to select more than one supplier, use a listbox or if you want checkboxes, you need a view model with a `bool IsSelected` property so it can be bound. And why does your action method return a JsonResult?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Firstable u cant do it like this.One way to do that is something like this.Here is the basic step how u do that.

1-assign for all checkbox ,checkbox change event with the unique id.
(take a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13912332/find-ids-of-checked-checkboxes-with-jquery-in-mvc))

2-Cretae a jquery object and store the data when ever the checkbox clicked ,via versa

```
var ListProductSuppliers ={ {ProductSupplier_info_here  },{ProductSupplier_info_here }  };
```

3-later via ajax request,serilize this object(`ListProductSuppliers` ) and send to your method

4-on server side deserilize this to the `IEnumerable<ProductSupplier>`

5 later do it whatever u want with those selected suppliars

Comment: This is rubbish. You don't need ajax at all. The problem is OP is using a `foreach` loop when a `for` loop or `EditorTemplate` is required

Comment: can u show me Some sample that i can use as reference.